# Manage the results of a HTTP request with google drive API

Tags: python

I've made a HTTP request with the google drive API method 'list' files and the result that I get is like this:

```
b'{\n "kind": "drive#file",\n "id": "0AilPd9i9ydNTdEh5bVhwSVVXckoyX1dfSXdHajM2a2c",\n "etag": "\\"A_UEsNCC1qXi5B_SXbPOKE8Swv0/MTM5NTU4OTc5OTM5Mw\\"",\n "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AilPd9i9ydNTdEh5bVhwSVVXckoyX1dfSXdHajM2a2c",\n "alternateLink": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AilPd9i9ydNTdEh5bVhwSVVXckoyX1dfSXdHajM2a2c&usp=drivesdk",\n "embedLink": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AilPd9i9ydNTdEh5bVhwSVVXckoyX1dfSXdHajM2a2c&output=html&chrome=false&widget=true",\n "iconLink": "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_11_spreadsheet_list.png",\n "title": "HiperAgenda_Copiada_4",\n "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",\n "labels": {\n  "starred": false,\n  "hidden": false,\n  "trashed": false,\n  "restricted": false,\n  "viewed": true\n },\n "createdDate": "2014-03-23T15:49:59.180Z",\n "modifiedDate": "2014-03-23T15:49:56.583Z",\n "modifiedByMeDate": "2014-03-23T15:49:56.583Z",\n "lastViewedByMeDate": "2014-03-23T15:49:56.583Z",\n "parents": [\n  {\n   "kind": "drive#parentReference",\n   "id": "0AClPd9i9ydNTUk9PVA",\n   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AilPd9i9ydNTdEh5bVhwSVVXckoyX1dfSXdHajM2a2c/parents/0AClPd9i9ydNTUk9PVA",\n   "parentLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AClPd9i9ydNTUk9PVA",\n   "isRoot": true\n  }\n ],\n "exportLinks": {\n  "application/pdf": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=0AilPd9i9ydNTdEh5bVhwSVVXckoyX1dfSXdHajM2a2c&exportFormat=pdf",\n  "application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=0AilPd9i9ydNTdEh5bVhwSVVXckoyX1dfSXdHajM2a2c&exportFormat=ods",\n  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=0AilPd9i9ydNTdEh5bVhwSVVXckoyX1dfSXdHajM2a2c&exportFormat=xlsx"\n },\n "userPermission": {\n  "kind": "drive#permission",\n  "etag": "\\"A_UEsNCC1qXi5B_SXbPOKE8Swv0/KJ48N7tGND1HtufOmBRKMH762wM\\"",\n  "id": "me",\n  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AilPd9i9ydNTdEh5bVhwSVVXckoyX1dfSXdHajM2a2c/permissions/me",\n  "role": "owner",\n  "type": "user"\n },\n "quotaBytesUsed": "0",\n "ownerNames": [\n  "Trimalcion Pertinax"\n ],\n "owners": [\n  {\n   "kind": "drive#user",\n   "displayName": "Trimalcion Pertinax",\n   "picture": {\n    "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-5I-SFuwKvcQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAACg0/K_XphE6_c_8/s64/photo.jpg"\n   },\n   "isAuthenticatedUser": true,\n   "permissionId": "17020090518219253183"\n  }\n ],\n "lastModifyingUserName": "Trimalcion Pertinax",\n "lastModifyingUser": {\n  "kind": "drive#user",\n  "displayName": "Trimalcion Pertinax",\n  "picture": {\n   "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-5I-SFuwKvcQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAACg0/K_XphE6_c_8/s64/photo.jpg"\n  },\n  "isAuthenticatedUser": true,\n  "permissionId": "17020090518219253183"\n },\n "editable": true,\n "copyable": true,\n "writersCanShare": true,\n "shared": false,\n "appDataContents": false\n}\n'
```

How can I manage it in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is json. Use [`json.loads`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to convert it to a dictionary.

```
response = b'{\n "kind": "drive#file"'

import json
result = json.loads(response.decode()) # Python 3.x
#result = json.loads(response) # Python 2.x
result['kind'] # => 'drive#file'
```

Comment: I don't know json, but I learned python dictionaries, I can manage a dictionary.  A lot of thanks @falsetru